# Why have some websites started showing only some of the words in another strange language?

Tags: google-chrome

In Google chrome, some websites have started showing some words in some other strange language. I want it all to appear in English.

Another problem I face is that for some reason Google chooses to select Google-Turkey as my search engine although I don't live in Turkey.

But this language doesn't even look like turkish.

How can I fix this?

[image]

---

***EDIT 1:***

[image]

Comment: The URL for the page you show includes "zh-CN" which is the code for Chinese (Traditional), so it is not surprising that the language of the page is Chinese - perhaps you clicked on the wrong link. As for the location, try searching for "change location on google" in google. Have you made sure that your region setting on your computer is correct? (you didn't mention which OS you are using).

Comment: You are on a Chinese language site, so it's not surprising that you are seeing Chinese characters: change the language selection at the bottom of the page. I have no idea why Google is choosing Turkey: where are you?

Comment: Are you signed in to Google? I assume so, if so, change your default settings manually - https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3333234?hl=en

Comment: If you (or your organisation) uses a web-proxy or filtering service based in another country, Google will think that's where you are browsing from.

Comment: @AFH The language is "English" at the bottom of the page. See the edit in the question, I am adding a screenshot.

Comment: @adelphus Yes I am using the Zenmate Google Chrome extension.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The timezone of Windows is set according to my location (if that's what you mean by "...region setting on your computer..."), but I am using a proxy extension in the browserI am using Windows 7.

Comment: @Solace Perhaps the best you can hope for is to append `english` to the end of your Google searches, seeing as you have intentionally hidden your location.

Comment: Selecting `English` should switch the URL to http://developer.android.com/training/index.html - have you disabled scripting? Plus, where is your proxy located?

Comment: @AFH The proxy is located in Romania (at-least that's what it shows). What do you mean by disabling scripting, if that means disabling Javascript, most of the websites won't function well if I disable javascript.

Comment: @AFH =O I changed from Chinese to Japenese and the page reloaded to show Japanese. Then I selected english, and the page reloaded and it's all English this time. I am posting it as answer so it might help future visitors.

Comment: I guess that somehow your pull-down language menu got out of step with the current language, so forcing a change brings them into step, and now changing back to English works as expected. I suspect that your proxy location is what is causing Google to give you the Turkish version. You should be able to go to `google.co.uk` or `google.ca` to get English-language searches: It's only `google.com` that gets mapped to a local version.

Comment: @AFH " I suspect that your proxy location is what is causing Google to give you the Turkish version." - May be, but even if I turn off the extension, the default search engine remains "google.com.tr". Even if I change it from "google.com.tr" to "google.co.uk" in Google Chrome Settings > Search > Manage Search Engines > Default search settings, it somehow reverts back to "google.com.tr" (even when the extension is turned off) even if restart Google Chrome. This is very annoying.

Comment: @AFH Nonetheless, I do believe it started because of the proxy extension, because I installed the same extension in Firefox and in a few days it started using Google-turkey for my searches. But if I go to google.co.uk website manually and then carry out my search, only then can I search using google.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the footer of the page, there is a drop-down menu of languages. It showed English, but the URL was `http://developer.android.com/zh-CN/training/index.html` which shoes that it is set to Chinese.

[image]

1. Click the expandable menu, a menu of languages will expand.
2. Choose any language other than English. The page will reload to show
   that language.
3. Scroll to the bottom again, and choose English. This time the page
   will reload again to the URL:
   `http://developer.android.com/training/index.html`, that is
   everything on the page will be in the English language.

   ---

**PS:** Most of the credit of this answer goes to the comments by @AFH, they told me about this languages menu at the bottom of the page.